# What's more elegant way to check for anagram?

Tags: anagram

I can't imagine better way to check for anagram than my solution:

```
def anagram(self,s,t):
        if len(s) != len(t):
            return False
        else:
            for elem1 in s:
                current_looking = elem1            
                if current_looking in t:
                    current_index = t.index(current_looking)
                    t = t[:current_index] + t[current_index+1:]
                else:
                    return False
            return True
```

Or this:

```
def anagram(s1,s2):
   return sorted(s1) == sorted(s2)
```

Or maybe there is another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is as succinct and faster than the sorting approach (O(n) < O(n log(n))):

```
from collections import Counter

def anagram(a, b):
    return Counter(a) == Counter(b)
```

You can boost performance at the expense of terseness:

```
def anagram(a, b):
    return len(a) == len(b) and Counter(a) == Counter(b)
```